# Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:pom:7.14.0-ee from/to camunda-bpm-nexus

Tags: maven, pom.xml, camunda, camunda-modeler

*I am trying to start "camunda web ee" but I am getting a lot of errors. Do you know how to fix the issue below I tried a lot of things but somehow it does not fix the error:*

*ERROR:*

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.adesso.camunda:springboot-edi-hub-camunda-ee:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\hub\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:pom:7.14.0-ee from/to camunda-bpm-nexus (https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public): PKIX pa
th building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 33, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-we
```

*in my settings.xml I have this:*

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"> 
  <servers>   
        <server>
          <id>camunda-bpm-ee</id>
          <username>account***</username>
          <password>password***</password>
         </server>
    </servers>
       <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>camunda-bpm</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

*and in my POM.xml as you can see I added the repository here in the pom. I tried also to call the repository in the Settings.xml file but it did not work it is always the same error. I have not idea why it is not working after trying everything that I found in google.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.camunda</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-edi-hub-camunda-ee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <camunda.version>7.14.0-ee</camunda.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
                <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${camunda.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>edireader-json-basic</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
            <artifactId>edireader</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus</name>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</name>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/repositories/camunda-bpm-ee</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>project.local</id>
            <name>project</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that fixes all problems, but in your pom.xml you refer to the EE Maven Repo with the name "camunda-bpm-nexus-ee":

```
<repository>
            <id>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</id>
            <name>camunda-bpm-nexus-ee</name>
            <url>https://app.camunda.com/nexus/content/repositories/camunda-bpm-ee</url>
        </repository>
```

And in your settings, you set the credentials for the name "camunda-bpm-ee"

```
 <server>
          <id>camunda-bpm-ee</id>
          <username>account***</username>
          <password>password***</password>
         </server>
```

You need to choose the same id in both places. See also https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/apache-maven/#enterprise-edition-1